# Segmentation fault in a C program

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault

Hello i require some assistance in solving a segmentation fault error. I am currently running debian 10.3 buster with the kernel 4.19.94-ti-r42. I have a c program that calls a PRU(programmable real time unit) program on my beaglebone black. The c program is and was compiled with:

```
gcc ledbutton.c -g ‐lpthread ‐lprussdrv
```

c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <prussdrv.h>
#include <pruss_intc_mapping.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PRU_NUM 0   // using PRU0 for these examples

int main (void)
{
   if(getuid()!=0){
      printf("You must run this program as root. Exiting.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   // Initialize structure used by prussdrv_pruintc_intc
   // PRUSS_INTC_INITDATA is found in pruss_intc_mapping.h
   tpruss_intc_initdata pruss_intc_initdata = PRUSS_INTC_INITDATA;

   // Allocate and initialize memory
   prussdrv_init ();
   prussdrv_open (PRU_EVTOUT_0);

   // Map PRU's interrupts
   prussdrv_pruintc_init(&pruss_intc_initdata);

   // Load and execute the PRU program on the PRU
   prussdrv_exec_program (PRU_NUM, "./ledButton.bin");

   // Wait for event completion from PRU, returns the PRU_EVTOUT_0 number
   int n = prussdrv_pru_wait_event (PRU_EVTOUT_0);
   printf("EBB PRU program completed, event number %d.\n", n);

   // Disable PRU and close memory mappings
   prussdrv_pru_disable(PRU_NUM);
   prussdrv_exit ();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After compiling i receive a `segmentation fault` error.  So i installed a gdb compiler to debug it and determine a possible source of error. using `gdb ./a.out` provides:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/debian/EBB_CH13/ledbutton/a.out
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6f9f470 in prussdrv_pruintc_init () from /usr/lib/libprussdrv.so
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb6f9f470 in prussdrv_pruintc_init () from /usr/lib/libprussdrv.so
#1  0x00400880 in main () at ledbutton.c:30
```

The contents of libprussdrv.so is encrypted so i cant view it. The pru program (ledbutton.bin) is in the same directory and is the result of compiling a assembly program (ledbutton.p) that blinks a led. The ledbutton.p code is and was compiled with:

```
pasm ‐b ledButton.p
```

assembly code:

```
.origin 0                        // start of program in PRU memory
.entrypoint START                // program entry point (for a debugger)

#define INS_PER_US   200         // 5ns per instruction
#define INS_PER_DELAY_LOOP 2     // two instructions per delay loop
                                 // set up a 50ms delay
#define DELAY  50 * 1000 * (INS_PER_US / INS_PER_DELAY_LOOP)

#define PRU0_R31_VEC_VALID 32    // allows notification of program completion
#define PRU_EVTOUT_0    3        // the event number that is sent back

START:
        SET     r30.t5           // turn on the output pin (LED on)
        MOV     r0, DELAY        // store the length of the delay in REG0
DELAYON:
        SUB     r0, r0, 1        // Decrement REG0 by 1
        QBNE    DELAYON, r0, 0   // Loop to DELAYON, unless REG0=0
LEDOFF:
        CLR     r30.t5           // clear the output bin (LED off)
        MOV     r0, DELAY        // Reset REG0 to the length of the delay
DELAYOFF:
        SUB     r0, r0, 1        // decrement REG0 by 1
        QBNE    DELAYOFF, r0, 0  // Loop to DELAYOFF, unless REG0=0

        QBBC    START, r31.t3    // is the button pressed? If not, loop

END:                             // notify the calling app that finished
        MOV     R31.b0, PRU0_R31_VEC_VALID | PRU_EVTOUT_0
        HALT                     // halt the pru program
```

Any help is appreciated. If you require more info, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: The second half of your post is irrelevant as the crash happens before it gets to that point. I'm not sure what help you expect as you don't have access to the source for `libprussdrv.so ` and have not even provided us with any API references for  those. The first thing to do would be to read the API reference and check whether the parameters being passed to it are correct. If that doesn't show anything then you need to speak to the owner of that module and/or reverse engineer the assembly.

Comment: Here is an API reference:  https://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Linux_Application_Loader_API_Guide

Comment: You should check the return values of the init and open functions. I suspect one of them has failed.

Comment: The reference has a minimal example of calling `prussdrv_pruintc_init`. Standard debugging would be to test with that minimal example first. If that still seg faults then you should raise a case with the vendor. There is really not much help we can give you for a closed source library.

Comment: I would also add the gcc compiler flag `-Wall` just in case it would generate any relevant warnings. But, I agree with @prl, checking return codes is always a good thing

Comment: @prl I have ran each function individually and the segmentation faults is due to `prussdrv_pruintc_init`. I cant seems to find info on what return value would signify an error for the  `prussdrv_init` and `prussdrv_open` but they compiled without error individually

Comment: when you dug into that function to find out what line(s) are causing it, what did you find?

Comment: @old_timer Do you mean the source code for prussdrv_pruintc_init? Im not to sure where the source file is located

Comment: How do you expect to debug it then?

Comment: Did you print the return values of init and open? Typically 0 means success and negative means an error. (Although it’s possible that 1 means success and 0 means error, but that’s less likely in a Linux package.)

Comment: @old_timer i found it on my system but i wont post it here. Here is the github link instead https://github.com/beagleboard/am335x_pru_package/blob/master/pru_sw/app_loader/interface/prussdrv.c

Comment: @prl strange, doing `a = prussdrv_init ();` produces a segmentation fault when i run the executable with `./test` which wont allow me to print the value. I am running this function individually.

Comment: @prl Each function can compile individually without a seg fault however when i run the executable with `./test` that is when the seg fault occurs

Comment: Maybe the default settings in `PRUSS_INTC_INITDATA` isn't compatible with your platform?

Comment: What happens, if you leave out the prussdrv_pruintc_init? Does the LED blink? Probably the end of the program is not detected in the main CPU without the interrupt.